# Python subprocess.Popen unable to parse argument

Tags: python

Trying to use Popen to launch multiple processes in separate shells, the process is an .exe file that takes arguments, when passing these arguments in a for loop since the variable changes and needs to be dynamically read every time the process runs, im facing issues as the program reports that it is not receiving the "COM" argument, but rather receiving "" string, however when printing the command the full thing shows properly as expected.

Using os.system works as expected but I need the CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE functionality.
Side note, how can i keep the shell running after the subprocess is complete ?

```
ports = serial.tools.list_ports.comports()
print(len(ports), 'port(s) found')
for p in ports:
    print(p.device)
    flasho_arg = f"-port {p.device} -app {K8_application} -launcher {launcher} -psoc {PSOC} -esp {esp} -graphics {graphics}"
    print(flasho_arg)
    #process = subprocess.Popen(["flasho.exe", flasho_arg], creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
    os.system(f"flasho.exe {flasho_arg}")
```

Comment: With subprocess you have to give all arguments as items in the array, not one item with executable and one with arguments.

Comment: Okay i figured out why it was not passing, the way im constructing the subprocess is wrong, ```process = subprocess.Popen(executable="flasho.exe", args=flasho_arg, creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)``` is the proper way.

Comment: But how about the shell persisting after the process is complete?

Comment: What shell? you're executing a program - not a shell. If you want the window to stay open - execute your python script from a terminal

Comment: Right, my bad. I was confused for a second. So that program returns an exit code, however using process.wait() in the loop makes it so that each process has to complete before the next one begins. Is there a smart way of running all processes and getting their exit code individually?